# Spark Iceberg table merge into update all

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-iceberg

I am trying to update the entire row when matched. I want this command to be an upsert.

`WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.* = updates.*` is not the right syntax.
How can I update the entire row?

```sql
MERGE INTO glue_catalog.{DATABASE_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME} target
USING (SELECT * FROM upsert_items) updates
ON {join_condidtion}
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.* = updates.*
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
```

Running Spark version 3.3.0-amzn-1
Iceberg v1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

[SparkSqlParser's grammar file](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/cdae4c6bb1949e7ddb7b834ffd887e3e9a3f30d8/sql/api/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBaseParser.g4#L596) has the following definition

```
matchedAction
    : DELETE
    | UPDATE SET ASTERISK
    | UPDATE SET assignmentList
    ;

notMatchedAction
    : INSERT ASTERISK
    | INSERT LEFT_PAREN columns=multipartIdentifierList RIGHT_PAREN
        VALUES LEFT_PAREN expression (COMMA expression)* RIGHT_PAREN
    ;

notMatchedBySourceAction
    : DELETE
    | UPDATE SET assignmentList
    ;
```

According to it, we can infer the SQL to be

```sql
MERGE INTO glue_catalog.{DATABASE_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME} target
USING (SELECT * FROM upsert_items) updates
ON {join_condidtion}
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET *
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
```

It works on Spark 3.3.4 with iceberg-spark-runtime-3.3_2.12:1.4.3

Answer (score -1):

Based on the example given with the `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *`, it should be the same for `UPDATE`.

```
MERGE INTO glue_catalog.{DATABASE_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME} target
USING (SELECT * FROM upsert_items) updates
ON {join_condidtion}
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE *
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
```